# What are the odds of a player drawing a specific card?

Tags: probability

I'm making a game and I need help figuring out the odds of something happening.

Every round is made up of 10 turns. Each turn, you have a 20% chance of landing on a BLUE square. There are 72 blue cards; 10% of those cards are "Level Up" cards. If four players are playing, what are the odds that in a round, at least one player will level up? I'm aware that the odds increase/decrease based on cards drawn, so I'm just looking for the base odds.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Each player gets $10$ turns? so $40$ turns are taken in total?  Are drawn cards discarded?  $10\%$ of $72$ isn't an integer...did you mean that exactly $7$ cards are "Level Up", all others irrelevant?

Comment: How can 10% of the blue cards "Level Up" cards ? $10\%\cdot 72=7.2$ Shouldn´t it be a whole number ?

Comment: What's the relationship between cards and squares? When you land on a blue square, do you draw a blue card?

Comment: Are the ten $20\%$ chances of landing on a blue square all independent?

Comment: @Sarah: you can edit your question to provide details that address all these comments, and then we can probably help answer the question that you really *intended* to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you draw one card when you land on a blue square and the chances are independent.  I will assume there are $7$ level up cards in the $72$ card deck.  We have $40$ trials.  The total number of cards drawn will follow a [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution).  The chance that $n$ cards are drawn is $p(n)=0.2^n0.8^{72-n}{40 \choose n}$, which has a maximum at $n=8$ of about $0.156$.  The chance that nobody levels up in $8$ tries is $\frac {65\cdot 64\cdot 63 \dots 59}{72 \cdot 71 \cdot \dots 66}=\frac {65!65!}{72!58!}\approx 0.4726$  To get your total chance of no level up, you need to sum over $n$, getting $$\sum_{n=0}^{40}p(n)\frac {65!(72-n+1)!}{72!(65-n+1)!}$$  The $p(n)$'s will fall rapidly after about $12$ or so.  To get the chance of at least one level up, subtract this sum from $1$